# In mongoose how can I insert array of daily sales to employee schema

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I want to insert an array of sales into the user array as I have a pos system that sends an array with the sales when ringing up the customer.  I just can't figure it out how to insert this array of sales into mongodb any help would be appreciated.

```
const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },

  sales: [

  ],
```

this is my code

```
const sales = [
  {
    id: "_dtrntuzsu",
    artist: "AC DC",
    sku: "00003",
    price: 14.9,
    type: "vinyl",
    inStock: 1,
  },
  {
    id: "_is7bnb792",
    artist: "Michael Jackson",
    sku: "00004",
    price: 6.9,
    type: "cd",
    inStock: 7,
  },
  {
    id: "_c8wm811mh",
    artist: "Britney Spears",
    sku: "00002",
    price: 8.5,
    type: "tape",
    inStock: 2,
  },
];

Employee.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "5ecc096ccb752d19d6d11130" },

  {
    $push: {
      sales: { $each: [sales2] },
    },
  },

  function (error, success) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(success);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: What's `sales2`? You have declared `sales` as an array. You can just `{ $push: { sales: { $each: sales } } }`

Comment: thanks and just wondering if theres a way I can set a date on the schema when this array is pushed.   sales: [ ],

Comment: Which schema? If any of them has a date field you can set a default as `default: Date.now`. Technically it's not on insert but on document object creation, but it should also be fine if you use it like you do